# Getting a link to be under an h3

Tags: html

I have a small project that I wrote. The goal is to have a section on the left of the website to show links to other sites. As of now, I have put the h3 that says "Links" on the same line as the paragraph tag.

What I want is to have the link that says "google" to be below the h3 tag that says "links". Right now it is above the h3 tag.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Link practice</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"/>

<h1>Welcome to my links</h1>

<p id = "paragraph"> Hello there! To the left you     can find links to other websites</p>

<h3 id = "h3">Links:</h3>

<ul id = "ul">
<li id = "li">
<a id = "a" href =     "http://www.google.com">google</a>
</li>
</ul>

</body
</html>
```

Here is the style sheet (style.css)

```
body 
{
background: lightgreen; 
}

a:hover 
{
color: white;
background: darkgreen;
}

h1 
{
text-align: center;
}

#h3
{
float: left;
}


#paragraph
{
float: right;
margin-right: 300px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would separate them using  tags so that you always have a space on the left to add to when you want to add more links.

Answer (score 0):

remove this from h3 css

```
float:left
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sh70z21/)